# unable to post data for registering new user in mysql database using postman

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, postman

I am trying to post data to phpmyadmin mysql database for registering new users using postman.

```
I have the following files and i am using visual studio code editor:
1) Constants.php
2) DbConnect.php
3) DbOperations.php
4) register.php
```

Files 1,2 and 3 are contained in "includes" folder inside shoppingapptut folder in htdocs. File 4 is contained in "v1" folder inside shoppingapptut folder in htdocs

[My Database Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5muyb.png)

[postMan post parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JUdf.png)

[PostMan Json Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqKub.png)

Constants.php Location:("C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Constants.php")

```
<?php
    define('DB_NAME','shoppingapptut');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','');
    define('DB_HOST','localhost');
?>
```

DbConnect.php ("C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Dbconnect.php")

```
<?php

    class DbConnect{
         private $con;

         function __construct(){

        }
    //Check con
    function connect(){
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Constants.php';
        $this-> con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if(msqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Failed to connect with database".mysqli_connect_err();
        }

        return $this->con;
    }

}
```

DbOperations.php ("C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\DbOperations.php")

```
<?php

    class DbOperations{
        private $con;

        //change equals with highphen 
        function __construct(){
            require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';
            $db = new DbConnect();
            $this->con = $db->connect();
        }

        public function createUser($firstname, $lastname, $phonenumber, $username, $email, $pass){
            if($this->isUserExist($username, $email)){
                return 0;
            }else{
                $password = md5($pass);
                $query = $this -> con -> prepare("INSERT INTO `customer` (`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`phonenumber`,
                `username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
                $query->bind_param("ssssss",$firstname,$lastname,$phonenumber,$username,$email,$password);

                if($query->execute()){
                    return 1;
                }else{
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }

        private function isUserExist($username, $email){
            $query = $this ->con-> prepare("SELECT id FROM customer WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
            $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
            $query->execute();
            $query->store_result();

            return $query->num_rows > 0;
        }
    }
?>
```

register.php ("C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\v1\register.php")

```
<?php

    require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';

    $response = array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        if(isset($_POST['firstname']) and isset($_POST['lastname']) and
        isset($_POST['phonenumber']) and isset($_POST['username']) and
        isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
            $db = new DbOperations();

            $result = $db->createUser( $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['phonenumber'], 
            $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );

            if($result == 1){
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = "Registration Success";
            }elseif($result == 2){
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "Some error occured please try again";
            }elseif ($result == 0) {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = "It seems you are already registered,please login or choose a different email and username";
            }
        }else {
            $response['error'] = false;
            $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
        }

    }else {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Am getting the following error on posting data:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_connect_errno() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Dbconnect.php:14
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\DbOperations.php(10): DbConnect->connect()

## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\v1\register.php(11): DbOperations->__construct()

## 2 {main}

thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Dbconnect.php** on line **14**

I want to be able to post new user data using postman and in doing soo register new user in the database

Comment: It looks like you've put the params in the query string, which is accessible via $_GET not $_POST. You probably meant to put them in the "Body" tab.

Comment: When i try that i get the following error

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_connect_errno() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Dbconnect.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\DbOperations.php(10): DbConnect-&gt;connect()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\v1\register.php(11): DbOperations-&gt;__construct()
#2 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingapptut\includes\Dbconnect.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />

Comment: So fix that. Seems an obvious typo. `msqli` vs `mysqli`.

Comment: Thanks working fine now